# How to auto replace link when have string "../"

Tags: php

I have a content

```
$content = '<img src="../test1.png"> and <img src="../../test2.png"> and <img src="../test3.png">';
```

This is my code:

```
$content = str_replace("../", "http://example.com", $content);
```

But result is wrong
How ideas show this result:

```
<img src="http://example.com/test1.png"> and <img src="http://example.com/test2.png"> and <img src="http://example.com/test3.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

using regex [preg_replace] :

```
$content = '<img src="../test1.png"> and <img src="../../test2.png"> and <img src="../test3.png">';
$replacement = 'http://example.com/';
$content = preg_replace('#(\.\.\/)+#', $replacement, $content);
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/BsAeF

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `explode`, `implode` and `array_filter`, Hope this would be helpful too.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794625)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$content = '<img src="../test1.png"> and <img src="../../test2.png"> and <img src="../test3.png">';
$array=array_filter(explode("../", $content));
print_r(implode("http://example.com/", $array));
```

**Output:**

`<img src="http://example.com/test1.png"> and <img src="http://example.com/test2.png"> and <img src="http://example.com/test3.png">`